# Using Apple Thunderbolt 2 monitor with Dell XPS 13 DE (Ubuntu 16.04) 9360

Tags: 16.04, drivers, xps, thunderbolt, usb-c

I recently got a new Dell XPS 13 DE after talking to a Dell support official who confirmed that with the appropriate adapter, this laptop would work with my Apple thunderbolt 2 monitor. However, it appears as though the support official was lying; that, or there is a lot of other steps to do after the factory install. So, the question here is, has anyone been able to get an Apple Thunderbolt 2 monitor working with their Dell XPS running Ubuntu? If so, what steps were done to get it working? Below is some information on my setup:

- Dell XPS 13 DE Model 9360
- Dell factory installed Ubuntu 16.04
- Kernel 4.9.0-040900-generic (manually updated from 4.4)
- Apple Thunderbolt 2 monitor
- Apple USB-C to Thunderbolt 2 adapter
- installed and ran Intel Graphics update tool for Linux

---

Kernel log of when Monitor/adapter is plugged in and unplugged

```
Apr  3 10:52:21 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [13764.148774] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
Apr  3 10:52:21 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [13764.149755] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: USB bus 3 deregistered
Apr  3 10:52:21 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [13764.150780] pcieport 0000:02:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
Apr  3 10:52:21 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [13764.153302] pci_bus 0000:03: busn_res: [bus 03] is released
Apr  3 10:52:21 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [13764.180750] pci_bus 0000:04: busn_res: [bus 04-38] is released
Apr  3 10:52:21 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [13764.240925] pci_bus 0000:39: busn_res: [bus 39] is released
Apr  3 10:52:21 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [13764.260869] pci_bus 0000:02: busn_res: [bus 02-39] is released
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.472934] ACPI Error: [SPRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20160831/dswload2-330)
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.472976] ACPI Exception: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20160831/psobject-227)
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.472985] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._E42] (Node ffff8ad9ad8e0578), AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20160831/psparse-543)
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.473004] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._E42] (Node ffff8ad9ad8e0578), AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20160831/psparse-543)
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.473026] ACPI Exception: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, while evaluating GPE method [_E42] (20160831/evgpe-646)
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.541619] pci 0000:01:00.0: [8086:1576] type 01 class 0x060400
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.541831] pci 0000:01:00.0: supports D1 D2
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.541834] pci 0000:01:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.542174] pci 0000:01:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.553315] pci 0000:02:00.0: [8086:1576] type 01 class 0x060400
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.553573] pci 0000:02:00.0: supports D1 D2
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.553576] pci 0000:02:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.553898] pci 0000:02:01.0: [8086:1576] type 01 class 0x060400
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.554133] pci 0000:02:01.0: supports D1 D2
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.554137] pci 0000:02:01.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.554443] pci 0000:02:02.0: [8086:1576] type 01 class 0x060400
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.554657] pci 0000:02:02.0: supports D1 D2
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.554661] pci 0000:02:02.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.554998] pci 0000:01:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 02-39]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.555017] pci 0000:01:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xc4000000-0xda0fffff]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.555030] pci 0000:01:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xa0000000-0xc1ffffff 64bit pref]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.555177] pci 0000:02:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 03]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.555195] pci 0000:02:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xda000000-0xda0fffff]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.555346] pci 0000:02:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04-38]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.555363] pci 0000:02:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xc4000000-0xd9efffff]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.555377] pci 0000:02:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xa0000000-0xc1ffffff 64bit pref]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.555587] pci 0000:39:00.0: [8086:15b5] type 00 class 0x0c0330
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.555626] pci 0000:39:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xd9f00000-0xd9f0ffff]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.555895] pci 0000:39:00.0: supports D1 D2
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.555899] pci 0000:39:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556255] pci 0000:02:02.0: PCI bridge to [bus 39]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556273] pci 0000:02:02.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd9f00000-0xd9ffffff]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556327] pci_bus 0000:02: Allocating resources
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556390] pci 0000:02:01.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 04-38] add_size 1000
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556409] pci 0000:02:02.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 39] add_size 1000
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556415] pci 0000:02:02.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 39] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556435] pci 0000:02:01.0: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 1000 min_align 1000
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556440] pci 0000:02:02.0: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 1000 min_align 1000
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556444] pci 0000:01:00.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 02-39] add_size 2000
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556451] pci 0000:01:00.0: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 2000 min_align 1000
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556455] pci 0000:01:00.0: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x2fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 2000 min_align 1000
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556463] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x2000]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556467] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x2000]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556473] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x2000]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556477] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x2000]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556487] pci 0000:02:02.0: res[15]=[mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] res_to_dev_res add_size 200000 min_align 100000
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556493] pci 0000:02:02.0: res[15]=[mem 0x00100000-0x002fffff 64bit pref] res_to_dev_res add_size 200000 min_align 100000
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556498] pci 0000:02:01.0: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 1000 min_align 1000
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556502] pci 0000:02:01.0: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x1fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 1000 min_align 1000
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556506] pci 0000:02:02.0: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 1000 min_align 1000
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556511] pci 0000:02:02.0: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x1fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 1000 min_align 1000
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556522] pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556526] pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556529] pci 0000:02:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556532] pci 0000:02:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556536] pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556538] pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556547] pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556550] pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556553] pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556557] pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556561] pci 0000:02:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556564] pci 0000:02:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556569] pci 0000:02:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 03]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556581] pci 0000:02:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xda000000-0xda0fffff]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556598] pci 0000:02:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04-38]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556608] pci 0000:02:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xc4000000-0xd9efffff]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556617] pci 0000:02:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xa0000000-0xc1ffffff 64bit pref]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556630] pci 0000:02:02.0: PCI bridge to [bus 39]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556641] pci 0000:02:02.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd9f00000-0xd9ffffff]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556657] pci 0000:01:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 02-39]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556668] pci 0000:01:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xc4000000-0xda0fffff]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.556676] pci 0000:01:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xa0000000-0xc1ffffff 64bit pref]
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.560152] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.560171] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.561424] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: hcc params 0x200077c1 hci version 0x110 quirks 0x00009810
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.561695] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.561701] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.561705] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.561709] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 4.9.0-040900-generic xhci-hcd
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.561712] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:39:00.0
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.562240] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.562261] hub 3-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.563301] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.563313] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.563407] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.563412] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.563416] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.563420] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 4.9.0-040900-generic xhci-hcd
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.563423] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:39:00.0
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.563827] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
Apr  3 11:01:23 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14306.563848] hub 4-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
Apr  3 11:01:24 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14307.160904] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Apr  3 11:01:24 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14307.484929] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Apr  3 11:01:24 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14307.628165] usb 3-1: No LPM exit latency info found, disabling LPM.
Apr  3 11:01:24 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14307.634458] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=1657
Apr  3 11:01:24 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14307.634464] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Apr  3 11:01:24 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14307.634468] usb 3-1: Product: Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter
Apr  3 11:01:24 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14307.634471] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
Apr  3 11:01:24 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14307.634473] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: DTN7024021YH2YF4E
Apr  3 11:01:28 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14311.533478] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: remove, state 4
Apr  3 11:01:28 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14311.533498] usb usb4: USB disconnect, device number 1
Apr  3 11:01:28 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14311.534144] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: Host not halted after 16000 microseconds.
Apr  3 11:01:28 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14311.535148] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: USB bus 4 deregistered
Apr  3 11:01:28 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14311.535166] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: remove, state 4
Apr  3 11:01:28 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14311.535179] usb usb3: USB disconnect, device number 1
Apr  3 11:01:28 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14311.535183] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
Apr  3 11:01:28 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14311.536347] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: USB bus 3 deregistered
Apr  3 11:01:28 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14311.537546] pcieport 0000:02:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
Apr  3 11:01:28 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14311.544165] pci_bus 0000:03: busn_res: [bus 03] is released
Apr  3 11:01:28 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14311.565004] pci_bus 0000:04: busn_res: [bus 04-38] is released
Apr  3 11:01:28 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14311.641098] pci_bus 0000:39: busn_res: [bus 39] is released
Apr  3 11:01:28 [system-name-excluded] kernel: [14311.657069] pci_bus 0000:02: busn_res: [bus 02-39] is released
```

---

UPDATE
- updated kernel to 4.10.8-041008-generic, no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for Apple Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapters is not quite there yet. Please refer to https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=189731 for details.